# How do I convert this to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

attachments is a CFDictionaryRef. How do I accomplish the (_bridge NSDictionary *) functionality in Swift?

```
CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer 
                                                  options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments];
```

**UPDATE**

here is the full code section I have tried for creating the CIImage.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var pixelBuffer:CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    var attachmentMode = CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
    var attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, attachmentMode)
    var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: attachments)

}
```

**ANSWER**

@NobodyNada's answer is correct, but because attachments is an 'unmanaged' CFDictionary you have to take the unretainedValue of the dictionary in order to clear the error. The correct answer is:

```
var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: attachments.takeUnretainedValue())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is called toll-free bridging, and it allows you to convert between certain Foundation and CoreFoundation types with a simple cast.  The `__bridge` thing was added with ARC because without it, ARC couldn't figure out enough information about it.  NSDictionaries and CFDictionaries are interchangeable in Swift without a cast:

```
let ciImage = CIImage(buffer: pixelBuffer, options: attachments).takeUnretainedValue()
```

P. S. Hi again:)  Sorry I couldn't answer your other question; I had to go suddenly.

Comment: Hello! haha...when I use the code you've provided I get the error "extra argument 'options' in call". I think it may be because attachments is an unmanaged CFDictionaryRef. That's why I thought I needed some sort of bridging functionality

Comment: I've included how I create attachments in my original question

Comment: Oh wait, you fixed it too!!

Comment: I think I have figured out the issue. Your answer is correct, however because attachments is 'unmanaged' you have to take the unretained value of it. I've posted what I believe is the correct solution above. Thanks again for your help and thorough explanation!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are going to want to use `takeRetainedValue()` to avoid a memory leak, but I'm a bit rusty on CF reference counting rules.  I'm looking it up right now...

Comment: hmm, good point. Probably better to be takeRetained to be safe. Although I would think Swift would handle the memory release?

Comment: Wait, you're right.  `takeUnretainedValue()` is like `__bridge`, but `takeRetainedValue` is like `__bridge_transfer`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74147/discussion-between-user3353890-and-nobodynada).